# Cumulative sum conditional over multiple columns in r dataframe containing the same values

Tags: r

Say my data.frame is as outlined below:

```
df<-as.data.frame(cbind("Home"=c("a","c","e","b","e","b"),
"Away"=c("b","d","f","c","a","f"))
df$Index<-rep(1,nrow(df))

   Home Away Index
1    a    b     1
2    c    d     1
3    e    f     1
4    b    c     1
5    e    a     1
6    b    f     1
```

What I want to do is calculate a cumulative sum using the Index column for each character a - f regardless of whether they in the `Home` or `Away` columns. Thus a column called `Cumulative_Sum_Home`, say, takes the character in the `Home` row, "b" in the case of row 6, and counts how many times "b" has appeared in either the `Home` or `Away` columns in all previous rows including row 6. Thus in this case b has appeared 3 times cumulatively in the first 6 rows, and thus the `Cumulative_Sum_Home` gives the value 3. Likewise the same logic applies to the `Cumulative_Sum_Away` column. Taking row 5, character "a" appears in the Away column, and has cumulatively appeared 2 times in either Home or Away columns up to that row, so the column `Cumulative_Sum_Away takes` the value 2.

```
 Home Away Index   Cumulative_Sum_Home  Cumulative_Sum_Away
1    a    b     1        1                    1
2    c    d     1        1                    1
3    e    f     1        1                    1
4    b    c     1        2                    2 
5    e    a     1        2                    2 
6    b    f     1        3                    2
```

I have to confess to being totally stumped as to how to solve this problem. I've tried looking at the `data.table` approaches, but I've never used that package before so I can't immediately see how to solve it. Any tips would be greatly received.

Comment: Before I go and do too much, are you able to confirm that the values in your real data frame will be factors? You can't `cumsum` factors as they are ordinal.

Comment: Hi - yes the values in the "Home" and "Away" columns in my real data frame are factors. I added the (numerical) "Index" column as a possible way to use the cumsum function to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is scope to make this leaner but if that doesn't matter much for you then this should be okay.

```
NewColumns = list()

for ( i in sort(unique(c(levels(df[,"Home"]),levels(df[,"Away"]))))) {

   NewColumnAddition = i == df$Home | i ==df$Away
   NewColumnAddition[NewColumnAddition] = cumsum(NewColumnAddition[NewColumnAddition])
   NewColumns[[i]] = NewColumnAddition

}


df$Cumulative_Sum_Home = sapply(
   seq(nrow(df)),
   function(i) {
      NewColumns[[as.character(df[i,"Home"])]][i]
   }
)


df$Cumulative_Sum_Away = sapply(
   seq(nrow(df)),
   function(i) {
      NewColumns[[as.character(df[i,"Away"])]][i]
   }
)



> df
  Home Away Index HomeSum AwaySum
1    a    b     1       1       1
2    c    d     1       1       1
3    e    f     1       1       1
4    b    c     1       2       2
5    e    a     1       2       2
6    b    f     1       3       2
```

Here's a `data.table` alternative -

```
setDT(df)
for ( i in sort(unique(c(levels(df[,Home]),levels(df[,Away]))))) {

   df[, TotalSum := cumsum(i == Home | i == Away)]
   df[Home == i, Cumulative_Sum_Home := TotalSum]
   df[Away == i, Cumulative_Sum_Away := TotalSum]

}
df[,TotalSum := NULL]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Codoremifa. I do not need a lean method of solution - and I can happily confirm that both methods you presented work exactly as required.